# TV out an iphone application

Tags: iphone

I would like to display my application running on iphone on a big screem, either TV or using a projector. After a long search I heard about the undocumented API MPTVOutWindow which fullfill's my requirement. But i think this is not approved by apple. Is there any other options available in latest SDK to TV out an application

Answer (score 2):

The class you want to look at is `UIScreen` it has support for external displays using the iPad VGA connector in iOS 3.2 (iPad) and iOS 4 (iPhone).

This blog post has a good example on how to use it: [mattgemmell.com: iPad VGA Output](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/06/01/ipad-vga-output)

Comment: Thank you Alan. I am upgrading my OS to iOS 4.0. Hope the external display support is available for iPod Touch 2G having iOS 4.0

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. Really found helpful.